# using Mann Whitney U test and t-test with multiple trials

Tags: t-test, repeated-measures, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am testing some visualisations under two conditions and this is a between-subjects study, participants do two trials. Initially, I separated the trials and used a Mann Whitney U test to analyse my dependent variable  (time). Now I have been advised to merge the two trials, Can I still use Mann Whitney? or will I have to change the test because now I have a repeated measure?

```
   participant  condition  time Task_type 
0         1194  E           20.0    G               
1         1194  E           70.0    S      
0         1190  P           42.0    G               
1         1190  P           30.0    S
```

I am thinking I could calculate the average for each participant and then use the Mann Whitney U test, could this work?

I have a similar question with another set of data that is ordinal and normally distributed and I used a t-test for that, can I calculate the average and use a t-test?